# How does Chrome App Launcher add itself?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

If I want to install the Chrome App Launcher and navigate to https://chrome.google.com/webstore/launcher , then click the only button over there, that page will install Chrome App Launcher shortcut to my Windows taskbar without any confirmation from the operating system whatsoever.

If I use a different browser, other than Chrome, I get redirected to the Chrome Webstore, with a message "You will need Google Chrome to install most apps, extensions and themes." showing. I guess, Chrome is able to place a shortcut from within a web page to my Desktop/Taskbar via its inner methods, as it's a general executable and may do "a lot" on its own.

How can I add my (any) shortcut from within a web page rendered in Chrome the same (or another) way the Chrome App Launcher has been installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, the webstore has special powers in chrome which regular web sites don't get. This is how it can also install extensions and apps, see whether you have particular extensions and apps installed, etc. You can see API by which it gets these special privileges [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/common/extensions/api/webstore_private.json).

This API is made available by chrome just to the webstore.